# How do I forward engineer in MySQL Workbench without losing objects?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mysql-workbench

How do I forward engineer my MySQL Model in the MySQL Workbench without losing the database's table rows?

I basically have a remote database with a users table with tuns of users in it. I also have a MySQL Model with the model of that remote database. In the model however, I have added 1 extra column to the users table. How do I add that column to the remote database without losing all users?

I have set a default value for the new column if that is a problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click on `Database -> Synchronize Model` or simply press `Shift + Control + Z`. A synchronization pop-up dialogue will appear and guide you through the process.

Comment: you save my day!! tks (I know this answer is for 2 year ago)